# Array, quantity of positive and negative numbers must be equal

Tags: java, arrays, random, range

- **quantity** of positive and negative numbers in array **must be equal**.
- an array mustn't contain **zero**.

The main issue is that array is not always consist of 50/50 of percent of positive and negative numbers.

If you can show me much simply way to code it you are welcome!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int array[] = new int[12];
        int positiveCounter = 0;
        int negativeCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = createRandom();
            while (array[i] == 0) {
                array[i] = createRandom();
            }

            if (positiveCounter > array.length / 2) {
                array[i] = -1 * array[i];
                positiveCounter--;
                negativeCounter++;
            }
            if (negativeCounter > array.length / 2) {
                array[i] = -1 * (-array[i]);
                negativeCounter--;
                positiveCounter++;
            }

            if (array[i] > 0) {
                positiveCounter++;
            }
            if (array[i] < 0) {
                negativeCounter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Pos: " + positiveCounter);
        System.out.println("Neg: " + negativeCounter);
    }

    static int createRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = -10 + random.nextInt(11 - (-10));
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with this code?  If so, then you need to [edit] your question to tell us what it is.  If not, then you need to be specific about what you want.

Comment: `new int[] { -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`

Comment: Does it make sense **The main issue is that array is not always consist of 50/50 of percent of positive and negatime numbers.**?

Comment: That is unfortunate.  I assume you've spent time in a debugger and can narrow your issue down to 2-3 lines?  Possibly helpful: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: whats wrong with creating 5 random negative numbers and then creating 5 random positive numbers and placing them in the array?

Comment: @Joe C. Thx
It's useful. I assume that the problem with my counters of positive and negative. Because, answers are always [5,7] or [6,6] or [7,5]. But, I can't catch it alone even though debugger.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz
It must be as random as possible.

Comment: *What* must be as random as possible? The length? The order? The elements? There are multiple variables and it's not clear what their constraints are.

Comment: @shmosel The lenght doesn't matter. The range doesn't matter. The only that really matter is quantity(**must be equal**) of positive and negative numbers inside the array. One more thing. Array like these:
[1,1,1,-1,-1,-1],
[1,-1,1,-1,1,-1],
doesn't fit me

Comment: Why not? What constraint does it violate?

Comment: @shmosel haha. You are funny. I have an issue. So, it's not about what does it constraint? It's about how could I fix it.

Comment: You're funny. How do you expect us to solve a problem that you won't define?

Comment: Here, this will generate 20 random numbers with an equal number of positives and negatives: `new Random().ints(10).flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(i, -i)).toArray()`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @shmosel Ok. Please, take a look. There is something that I see after the programe is finished:
[-4, 5, -3, 1, 10, -8, -4, 7, -1, 4, 1, 3]
Pos: 7
Neg: 5
**Pos and Neg are different.** Is it OK? Everything fine if its 6, 6 in this case.

Comment: @shmosel is it possible to find a zero inside the array? If so, nope. It doesn't fit me.

Comment: Ok, change it to `.ints().filter(i -> i != 0).limit(10)`. Or `.ints(10, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: @shmosel Am I right that there won't be only the positive or only the negative numbers? And theirs quantity will be equal? Imagine that ethalon array consist of [10,0)(0,10]

Comment: Aside from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which doesn't have a positive counterpart, that's correct.

Comment: @shmosel any differences with [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1] ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments may lead to a very compact way to achieve your goal, but for what it is worth I'd like to explain why your code is not working as expected, and show a way that it will.

You attempt to invert the sign to keep the amount of positive and negative numbers balanced.  This will work, but you have a flaw in your code.  You must only invert the number if the current number needs to be inverted.  If you look at this code you will see it always inverts and adjusts the counters even if array[i] is negative (in which case nothing needs to be done):

```
if (positiveCounter > array.length / 2) {
     array[i] = -1 * array[i];   // <- This is a problem
     positiveCounter--;
     negativeCounter++;
}
```

To follow should fix your issue; the inversion is only done as needed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = createRandom();
        while (array[i] == 0) {
            array[i] = createRandom();
        }
        if (positiveCounter >= array.length / 2 && array[i] > 0) {
            array[i] = array[i] * -1;   // Force the number to be negative
        }
        if (negativeCounter >= array.length / 2 && array[i] < 0) {
            array[i] = array[i] * -1;   // Force the number to be positive
        }
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            positiveCounter++;
        }
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            negativeCounter++;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thx a lot!
Is my method the easiest? to create an array like this.

Comment: No problem.  Your method is intuitive, and correct.  That is all that matters.

Comment: My hero ;) My method isn't 100% mine. Cheers